# Using @QueryParam in Spring

Tags: java, spring, parameters

I'm looking for a simple example of using @QueryParam in Spring.
My thought is to have an link as that looks like this that will get the id value, run my java class and present the String that is returned. My problem is that the returning value is not found.

http://localhost:8080/recipesinfo?id=274596

There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "recipesinfo.step" (template: "recipesinfo_result" - line 12, col 22)

DemoApplication.java

```
RecipesInfo repinfo = new RecipesInfo();
@RequestMapping("/recipesinfo")
public String getInfo (@RequestParam("id") int id) throws IOException {

    repinfo.execute(id);

    return "recipesinfo_result";
 }




public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);

}
```

recipesinfo_result.html

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Recipes</title>
</head>
<body>
<p class="title"><a  th:text="${recipesinfo.step}"></a><br></body>
</html>
```

RecipesInfo.java

```
public String execute(int id) throws IOException { 

//using id in a Http request here and returning String step (the problem isn't here)

      return step;
      }
```

I have done something similar to this in a Web Service which is working but that one is just returning JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind your query parameters to model for pass it to your view page.

```
@RequestMapping("/recipesinfo")
public String getInfo (@RequestParam("id") int id, Model theModel)) throws IOException {
    theModel.addAttribute("recipesinfo",id);

    return "recipesinfo_result";
 }
```

recipesinfo_result.html

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Recipes</title>
</head>
<body>
<p class="title"><a  th:text="${recipesinfo}"></a><br></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this way I just get the id on my html-page, I want to get the String step, that is returned by RecipeInfo.java.

Comment: Thanks alot anyway! I found out how to solve it with your response :)

  String s = repinfo.execute(id);
  
  model.addAttribute("recipesinfo", s);
     
     return "recipesinfo_result";